# How to read json file in android?

Tags: android, json

I have created a json file. This file need to copy to a another file.This is the json file.

```
[
 {
  "Number": "0123456789",
  "Date": "Tue Jul 21 14:30:34 GMT+00:00 2015",
  "message": "Hello i'm older"
 }
][
 {
  "Number": "0123456789",
  "Date": "Tue Jul 21 14:35:22 GMT+00:00 2015",
  "message": "Hello i'm older"
 }
][
 {
  "Number": "0123456789",
  "Date": "Tue Jul 21 14:35:24 GMT+00:00 2015",
  "message": "Hello i'm older"
 }
]
```

I'm reading this file and put it in another file. This is what i tried.

```
private void copyFile(File file) throws IOException {
        String TAG = "MyTest";
        Toast.makeText(this, "copyFile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FileInputStream in = openFileInput("backupMessage.json");
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            String number = null;
            String date = null;
            String message = null;
            reader.beginObject();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String name = reader.nextName();
                if (name.equals("Number")) {
                    number = reader.nextString();
                    Log.d(TAG, number);
                } else if (name.equals("Date")) {
                    date = reader.nextString();
                    Log.d(TAG, number);
                } else if (name.equals("message")) {
                    message = reader.nextString();
                    Log.d(TAG, number);
                } else {
                    reader.skipValue();
                    Log.d(TAG, "skip");
                }
            }
            if(number != null && date != null && message != null){
                writer(file, number, date, message);
                Log.d(TAG, "called writer");
            }
            reader.endObject();
        }
        reader.endArray();
        reader.close();
    }

    private void writer(File file,String number,String date, String message){
        Toast.makeText(this, "writer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FileOutputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
            JsonWriter jwriter = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream,"UTF-8"));
            jwriter.setIndent(" ");
            jwriter.beginArray();
            jwriter.beginObject();
            jwriter.name("Number").value(number);
            jwriter.name("Date").value(date);
            jwriter.name("message").value(message);
            jwriter.endObject();
            jwriter.endArray();
            jwriter.close();
            stream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But this is not working. Thats means it is not reading the whole file. it is reading only a first node.How can i read the whole file ?

Comment: Are you expecting to work with a large file? If not, you could simply use [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: @Knossos actually i need to copy file content with modyfing it's data.

Comment: If you need to parse JSON in order to copy your data with some modifications, you must make your JSON valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHange your JSON to

```
[
    {
        "Number": "0123456789",
        "Date": "Tue Jul 21 14:30:34 GMT+00:00 2015",
        "message": "Hello i'm older"
    },
    {
        "Number": "0123456789",
        "Date": "Tue Jul 21 14:35:22 GMT+00:00 2015",
        "message": "Hello i'm older"
    },
    {
        "Number": "0123456789",
        "Date": "Tue Jul 21 14:35:24 GMT+00:00 2015",
        "message": "Hello i'm older"
    }
]
```

Then, you can parse it like that:

```
try
{
    JSONObject tmp = null;
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(YOUR_JSON_AS_A_STRING);
    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++)
    {
        tmp = array.getJSONObject(i);
        writer(file, tmp.getString("Number"), tmp.getString("Date"), tmp.getString("message"));
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is needed to parse the JSON in order to copy the file at all. BUT, **your JSON seems to be invalid**. If you need to parse the JSON in order to copy your data with some modifications, you must make your JSON valid.